# Adding form inputs in javascript (jquery)

Tags: jquery

I understand that you do something like:

```
$('form').append('<input type="text" name="color-1" value="Hello" />');
```

But I have two questions about it. First off, I don't want it added to the end of the form, but after the last input in the "color" section. Secondly, where "name=color-1", I need the one to increment if they want to add more than one input, you know? So that I can process it on the server.

Any ideas?

Comment: One idea would be to learn some basic javascript.

Comment: As blunt is fig-gnuton is, he's actually right. It won't take you too long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is the `.after()` // `.insertAfter()` function.
Let's say you have a DIV with the class "color" within your form, you would do

```
$('form').find('.color > :input').last().after('<input type="text" name="" value=""/>');
```

To add more of those input fields, just add a button or anything else which is capable
of executing a click event, where you can execute code to insert more inputs.

Comment: A slight adjustment to the selector (if I understand the question right) would be `$('form').find(':input[name*=color]').last()`